# [ios & cloud]Cloud storage service for iOS development?

Tags: ios, cloud, asihttprequest, restkit

I am looking for some web service for storing some data from iOS applications.

ASIHttpRequest supports two cloud service

http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/Cloud-Files
http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/S3

[Restkit](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/restkit_ios-sdk/) is good way for communication.

I am not sure I can get some answers here. Just want any clues or suggest if you can share.

My purpose is to look for some free storage service for this. Are there any existed ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Obviously Apple recently announced iCloud, but it is still under NDA so we cannot discuss the development implications.  If you are just looking for a place to store files, I would recommend Amazon S3.  You can use the link you have above for S3 or the official Amazon AWS SDK for iOS:

http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforios/